# Discrepancies between source and inspected html?

Tags: html, css

I am editing a HTML website template, and I need to change the banner height so I edited external CSS. However, somehow it is taking an inline CSS height property so there is a space left in between.
Please let me know, if I have not written any inline CSS (and there is no inline CSS in html page), from where is that height property coming from.

Code I see in console is:
`<div style="display: block; height: 445px;" id="camera" class="camera-wrap camera_wrap">`

And my code is:

```
<div id="camera" class="camera-wrap">
<div data-src="images/Battery-Banner.jpg">
```

I have no idea why it is taking class camera_wrap twice.

Comment: May be it will assign through jquery code.

Comment: I am not sure from where it is coming from, but if you want to force the height defined in the CSS class to take precedence over the inline one, try this syntax in your CSS class "height:40px !important;" [40px is just sample, change it to whatever value you need]

Comment: tried ur suggestion...still not working  :(

Comment: oh sry...dat was my mistake i put !important in wrong place....its working now after putting in right place :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually JS plugins put dynamic css that is calculated during runtime. It will be placed in inline style tag. Otherwise any static code will go to external css file. Try checking how plugin is calculating that height and than modify your HTML/css.

Answer (score 0):

Try viewing the HTML source in your browser (not using inspect element, use view-source). This will show you the markup prior to any other client side processing aka. JavaScript. If the inline style isn't there when you view source then that indicates that it may be a rogue bit of JavaScript that is adding it in.

In any case can you please provide more information on the issue? Possibly a little more background on what type of website, what parts it has CSS, JS etc. With more information we may be able to help more.

Comment: I can see my html code when i see by choosing view sourcecode. the site is basic html site with jquery plugins for banner slideshow etc. i wanted to attach a screenshot but i cannot since my reptation is below 10 :(

Comment: In that case it does sound like there is some JavaScript running that is altering your classes. You will need to look at the included scripts to see if you can find the class it's adding.

Comment: i tried to...but i am not very knowledgable in Js and jquery...but as per my search i cudnt find any height...

Answer (score 0):

If your source is showing 1 class, and when you are using inspect element it is showing other classes, then it is definitely added by js/jquery plugin.

If you want to overwrite other class css properties, either use !important in your class or use deeper dom traversing like #camera.camera-wrap{}. Than this will be given higher priority. Try which works for you.